# How do I create (intercept) editor for TcxScheduler schedule event?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, scheduler

I have a `TcxScheduler` where I would like to be able to get the value of a customfield when I dblclick the event.
It is quite simple to catch the dblclick event, but I am having trouble getting the event that is clicked.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate? What trouble are you having? How looks you code related to this event? How have you set up that custom field?

Comment: Assuming cxScheduler comes from DevExpress, you could be better of asking in their support forums.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: DevExpress is also present on Stackoverflow (cf. [DevExpress Team](http://stackoverflow.com/users/380926/devexpress-team), last activity Feb 8 at 9:26 as of the time of my post).

Comment: @OZ8HP: Please provide some minimal code if you expects valuable answers. How could people better reproduce your issue otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use the SchedulerBeforeEditing

```
procedure TFrmScheduler.SchedulerBeforeEditing(Sender: TcxCustomScheduler;
         AEvent: TcxSchedulerControlEvent; AInplace: Boolean; var Allow: Boolean);
var
  MyValue: Variant;  
begin
  inherited;
  if not AInplace  then
  begin
    try
      if  AEvent.Index = -1 then
      begin
        // do something like Add new event
      end
      else
      begin
        MyValue:=AEvent.GetCustomFieldValueByName('SomeField');
        // do something 
      end;
    finally
      // ingore the edit
      Allow:= False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It depend what OZ8HP just want to do. If OZ8HP wants a new event on dblclick or he want a self maked editform with the costumfields then i prefer to use the SchedulerBeforeEditing

Comment: that solution does the trick for me.

What I am working on is a calendar form where all the backups made by my app is listed as an event and then the user can dblclick on of those to be able to restore the data from that file.
Might be a bit overkill but it looks nice and I think it is a good way of showing the user when backups were made.